# How do I get the correct bounds of a view after an orientation change?

Tags: iphone, ios6, ipad

I am using view.bounds to determine where to add a date picker view when a button is pressed. This works just fine if the orientation if the same as it was when the view was navigated to. Unfortunately if the orientation changes while the view is displayed the bounds are not undated, so the picker view is displayed incorrectly. I need a way to determine the actually bounds of the view. I would like something that works in both iPad and iPhone if possible because this is for a universal app. Also in the iPad version the picker view is in a splitview detail controller so I can't just swap the height and width and adjust for the navigation bar.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
   [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];

   // size up the picker view to our screen and compute the start/end frame origin for      our slide up animation
   //
   // compute the start frame

    CGRect screenRect = self.view.bounds;
    CGSize pickerSize = [self.pickerView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    CGRect startRect;
    CGRect pickerRect;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
    {
        // code for Portrait orientation
        startRect = CGRectMake(0.0,
                               screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height,
                               pickerSize.width, pickerSize.height);
        pickerRect = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height - pickerSize.height,
                                screenRect.size.width,
                                pickerSize.height);

    }
    else
    {
        //code for landscape
        startRect = CGRectMake(0.0,
                               screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height,
                               pickerSize.width, pickerSize.height);
        pickerRect = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height - pickerSize.height,
                                screenRect.size.width,
                                pickerSize.height);


    }

    self.pickerView.frame = startRect;

    // start the slide up animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    // we need to perform some post operations after the animation is complete
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    self.pickerView.frame = pickerRect;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the pickerview to an action sheet like so:

```
UIActionSheet *aac = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose Date and Time"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];


[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

pickerDateToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerDateToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[pickerDateToolbar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[pickerDateToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

[aac addSubview:pickerDateToolbar];
[aac addSubview:datePicker];

[aac showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
CGFloat wideth = self.view.frame.size.width;
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([self interfaceOrientation])) {
   [aac setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,wideth, 355)];
   [datePicker sizeToFit];
} else {
    [aac setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0, wideth, 470)];
    [datePicker sizeToFit];
}
picker = aac;
```

Hope that this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your issue, you should try and set:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

on your views so that they bounds are "updated" when the orientation changes.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Now in portait it gives a wideth of 320 and a height of 416, which is correct. However it give 480 for wideth and 484 for height when in landscape. This is no correct at all. The view is a tableview coule that have something to do with it?

Comment: I think the code in your `didRotate...` is in the wrong place (it is too late). I would suggest moving `didRotate...` body into `-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and see if it improves. Or: what happens if you disable that code altogether?